# Is it possible to set up a board state where neither player can ever win or lose except by conceding?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A [Platinum Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=425817) and [Laboratory Maniac](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=230788) for both players would take care of most game endings but either one could be removed from play in a variety of ways. [Mycosynth Lattice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=50527) and [Darksteel Forge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370734) would negate combat damage and destroy effects but not exile or sacrifice effects.

Edit: Ideally, fo maximum troll the boardstate should be reachable with only one player working towards it.

Comment: Let each player play an [Enduring Ideal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=87598) with no enchantments in their libraries, and you're have negated a lot of possibilities. But why not let each player just play a deck with no win condition in it, and something which makes them not lose from drawing with no cards left, like [Island Sanctuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202556)?

Comment: Island Sanctuary is a 'may', so you can still deck yourself. Ideally, and I will edit the question to reflect this, for maximum troll the state should theoretically be reachable  with only one player working towards it

Comment: You’re over-complicating it. All you need is: both players have nothing but Platinum Angel on the battlefield, and both players have no cards in their library or hand. There’s all sorts of ways to reach this; simplest way would just be that they both had a deck of 59 Plains and 1 Platinum Angel.

Comment: Heh, guilty. I do love overcomplicating.

Answer (score 5):

Arcanist Lupis already provided a fine answer, which works in most circumstances, but you said that you wanted "maximum troll", so I'll provide an alternative solution, which doesn't require Platinum Angel or Abyssal Persecutor (Please note that this solution requires an arbitrary amount of mana):

1. Cast [Temple Bell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=420894), [Omen Machine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233042), [Auratog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=106665), and [Hive Mind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=190556).
2. Cast [Deadeye Navigator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=425861) and [Dualcaster Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=430585), and soulbond them.
3. Cast [Oblivion Ring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397760), and exile your Omen Machine.
4. Cast [Enter the Infinite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366411) (which each player has to copy), then tap your Temple Bell. Each player now has every card in their library in their hand.
5. Sacrifice Hive Mind to Auratog (This prevents our opponents from messing up our combo in step 7).
6. Cast [Worldfire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=278195).
7. With Worldfire on the stack, cast [Pull from Eternity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=106657) on any permanents in exile that have the potential to impact the board state after the Worldfire resolves, such as suspended cards or a creature exiled with [Flickerform](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=430230). Use the Deadeye Navigator to flicker the Dualcaster Mage, and copy the Pull from Eternity as needed. Note that in the case of Flickerform, you will always receive priority after its ability resolves, so you can still target cards that were exiled while Worldfire was on the stack.
8. Laugh maniacally (This step is very important!)

When Worldfire resolves, your Oblivion Ring will be exiled, returning Omen Machine to the battlefield. The result? No players will have any cards in their hands, libraries, or graveyards. The only permanent in play will be Omen Machine, preventing players from losing the game via decking themselves. Assuming no phasing shenanigans, no player will be able to do anything, effectively locking everybody out of winning or losing the game.

Comment: Would Flickerform be a counter to this?

Comment: @Acccumulation it absolutely would be. I'll edit in a workaround for that

Comment: Don't you need to force a draw before the Worldfire? Otherwise each player gets a single card, which could be a Pact.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus That's what the Temple Bell is for. Do you think I should edit that step to make it more explicit?

Comment: No, I just can't read. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding Arthur's comment:

First, make sure that neither player has a method of dealing damage present on the battlefield.  I personally recommend [Jokulhaups](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=159235), but remember to float the mana you'll need to do everything else (17UBBR).  If they have any damage dealing enchantments, you'll have to deal with those separately, but those are pretty rare.

Second, play [Omen Machine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233042), [Blood Moon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=425915), and [Hive Mind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=190556).

Finally, play [Neverending Torment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=87601).

Now nobody can play spells or deck themselves (one of the nuances of decking yourself is that you only lose when you try to draw and find no cards left.  Any other library interactions just fail on an empty library).  The lands you play will have no abilities.  If you've already cleared the board of any sources of damage or other things that might break the lock, everybody is well and truly stuck.

Comment: I want to see this.  I also want to see someone use Pact of Negation on Neverending Torment.  That would be some crazy kingmaker-ing there.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with [Platinum Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=425817) and [Abyssal Persecutor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=438644) together.

To keep them alive, you can use an [Ascetism](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=215082) for hexproof and regeneration, or [Cauldron of Souls](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=420863) with a few [Chainbreaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=147419) to protect against sacrifice, too.

I can't say "neither player can *ever* win or lose", but for "maximum troll" and some more protection, check out [Sen Triplets](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=180607).

Comment: Broken by [Final Judgement](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=81991) (Exile all creatures)

Comment: Cauldron of Souls would NOT help, game losses would evaluate before persist resolves, the angel/persecutor would be in the graveyard, SBAs would be checked before persist goes on stack, causing anyone with a valid loss condition to lose before the creatures returned to play.

Comment: Or my favorite board wipe: [Merciless Eviction](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=433111)